# Undefined property: DOMElement::$tagName

Tags: error

When I am logged into the admin control panel and I go to "Settings", I receive the error `"Undefined property: DOMElement::$tagName"`.

Here is the Stack Trace:

```js
yii\base\ErrorException: Undefined property: DOMElement::$tagName in /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/enshrined/svg-sanitize/src/Sanitizer.php:312
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(76): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError()
#1 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/enshrined/svg-sanitize/src/Sanitizer.php(312): craft\web\ErrorHandler->handleError()
#2 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/enshrined/svg-sanitize/src/Sanitizer.php(223): enshrined\svgSanitize\Sanitizer->startClean()
#3 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Html.php(694): enshrined\svgSanitize\Sanitizer->sanitize()
#4 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/twig/Extension.php(1183): craft\helpers\Html::sanitizeSvg()
#5 /var/www/QP CMS/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/96/964f7e4291a1e942d9ff12501169ffc699fdfea327c917f885389e07e4129c7c.php(107): craft\web\twig\Extension->svgFunction()
#6 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(184): __TwigTemplate_7c33a11a3443e3f6abdd7210ca6bc46b4abc8c987ccff0a049083e9818cce5a3->block_content()
#7 /var/www/QP CMS/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/79/79c784ae009da993252e082098eb6375c8755a63c09dd04e9911a326fe7f411e.php(444): Twig\Template->displayBlock()
#8 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(184): __TwigTemplate_6d81c2ee1a2e2035aa01483b4f8a52a955d85721eca94d19574adf28c23fddd3->block_main()
#9 /var/www/QP CMS/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/79/79c784ae009da993252e082098eb6375c8755a63c09dd04e9911a326fe7f411e.php(309): Twig\Template->displayBlock()
#10 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(184): __TwigTemplate_6d81c2ee1a2e2035aa01483b4f8a52a955d85721eca94d19574adf28c23fddd3->block_body()
#11 /var/www/QP CMS/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/ce/ce9a9339170ac3c6f680771106f515b112fa038494f89d91df1463ff4fc06c35.php(85): Twig\Template->displayBlock()
#12 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(407): __TwigTemplate_2fbb7b3ad69d2f6fff9aa70bbf9ae8aa3bba2af96b1ca34a6e1143d065a26047->doDisplay()
#13 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(380): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling()
#14 /var/www/QP CMS/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/6c/6c2a177ee6b793461763000f70e8d66d727d8c7db7d046ae8d90e5a81e34ea84.php(56): Twig\Template->display()
#15 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(407): __TwigTemplate_70b9c892efaf45b75ae95716a323cf34eae7751a834be7ce17e5e6af74795bf7->doDisplay()
#16 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(380): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling()
#17 /var/www/QP CMS/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/79/79c784ae009da993252e082098eb6375c8755a63c09dd04e9911a326fe7f411e.php(154): Twig\Template->display()
#18 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(407): __TwigTemplate_6d81c2ee1a2e2035aa01483b4f8a52a955d85721eca94d19574adf28c23fddd3->doDisplay()
#19 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(380): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling()
#20 /var/www/QP CMS/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/96/964f7e4291a1e942d9ff12501169ffc699fdfea327c917f885389e07e4129c7c.php(48): Twig\Template->display()
#21 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(407): __TwigTemplate_7c33a11a3443e3f6abdd7210ca6bc46b4abc8c987ccff0a049083e9818cce5a3->doDisplay()
#22 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(380): Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling()
#23 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Template.php(392): Twig\Template->display()
#24 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/TemplateWrapper.php(45): Twig\Template->render()
#25 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(318): Twig\TemplateWrapper->render()
#26 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(392): Twig\Environment->render()
#27 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/View.php(453): craft\web\View->renderTemplate()
#28 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(251): craft\web\View->renderPageTemplate()
#29 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/TemplatesController.php(100): craft\web\Controller->renderTemplate()
#30 [internal function]: craft\controllers\TemplatesController->actionRender()
#31 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()
#32 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(180): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams()
#33 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(189): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#34 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction()
#35 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(274): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#36 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction()
#37 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(259): yii\web\Application->handleRequest()
#38 /var/www/QP CMS/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest()
#39 /var/www/QP CMS/web/index.php(22): yii\base\Application->run()
#40 {main}
```

Comment: Can you enable [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#devmode) and edit the question to share the full stack trace leading up to that error?

Comment: Looks like it's choking trying to render an SVG on the Settings page, so my guess is you've got a plugin installed that is trying to display its logo on that page and the SVG is in an invalid format? Or at least a format that Craft doesn't know what to do with. You can try using the `craft plugin/uninstall` command from the project's root to narrow down which one.